# Power BI Transformation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to transform a calendar table I have in PowerBI.

The calendar data looks like this:

| Name | Event | Detail | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | Event A | Detail A | 12/2/2020 | 15/2/2020 |
| Name 2 | Event A | Detail A | 12/2/2020 | 15/2/2020 |
| Name 3 | Event A | Detail A | 12/2/2020 | 15/2/2020 |
| Name 2 | Event B | Detail B | 22/2/2020 | 25/2/2020 |
| Name 3 | Event B | Detail B | 22/2/2020 | 25/2/2020 |
| Name 4 | Event B | Detail B | 22/2/2020 | 25/2/2020 |
| Name 1 | Event C | Detail C | 23/2/2020 | 27/2/2020 |

And I want it to look like this:

| Name | Event | Detail | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | Event A | Detail A | 12/2/2020 |
| Name 1 | Event A | Detail A | 13/2/2020 |
| Name 1 | Event A | Detail A | 14/2/2020 |
| Name 1 | Event A | Detail A | 15/2/2020 |
| Name 2 | Event A | Detail A | 12/2/2020 |
| Name 2 | Event A | Detail A | 13/2/2020 |
| Name 2 | Event A | Detail A | 14/2/2020 |
| Name 2 | Event A | Detail A | 15/2/2020 |
| Name 3 | Event A | Detail A | 12/2/2020 |
| Name 3 | Event A | Detail A | 13/2/2020 |
| Name 3 | Event A | Detail A | 14/2/2020 |
| Name 3 | Event A | Detail A | 15/2/2020 |
| Name 2 | Event B | Detail B | 22/2/2020 |
| Name 2 | Event B | Detail B | 23/2/2020 |
| Name 2 | Event B | Detail B | 24/2/2020 |
| Name 2 | Event B | Detail B | 25/2/2020 |
| Name 3 | Event B | Detail B | 22/2/2020 |
| Name 3 | Event B | Detail B | 23/2/2020 |
| Name 3 | Event B | Detail B | 24/2/2020 |
| Name 3 | Event B | Detail B | 25/2/2020 |
| Name 4 | Event B | Detail B | 22/2/2020 |
| Name 4 | Event B | Detail B | 23/2/2020 |
| Name 4 | Event B | Detail B | 24/2/2020 |
| Name 4 | Event B | Detail B | 25/2/2020 |
| Name 1 | Event C | Detail C | 23/2/2020 |
| Name 1 | Event C | Detail C | 24/2/2020 |
| Name 1 | Event C | Detail C | 25/2/2020 |
| Name 1 | Event C | Detail C | 26/2/2020 |
| Name 1 | Event C | Detail C | 27/2/2020 |

How can I do this in the query editor?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend any names as required.

```
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content], 
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    Source, 
    {
      {"Name", type text}, 
      {"Event", type text}, 
      {"Detail", type text}, 
      {"Start Date", type date}, 
      {"End Date", type date}
    }
  ), 
  #"Added Column: Number of Days" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Changed Type", 
    "Total Days", 
    each 1 + Duration.Days([End Date] - [Start Date])
  ), 
  #"Added Column: List" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Added Column: Number of Days", 
    "Days to Add", 
    each {1 .. [#"Total Days"]}
  ), 
  #"Expanded Days to Add" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Column: List", "Days to Add"), 
  #"Added Column: New Dates" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Expanded Days to Add", 
    "Custom", 
    each Date.AddDays([Start Date], [Days to Add] - 1), 
    type date
  )
in
  #"Added Column: New Dates"
```

Comment: Thanks @Jos Woolley,

That transformed the data in the query editor but returned this error when I saved and exited back into the report:

OLE DB or ODBC error: [Expression.Error] We cannot apply operator .. to types Number and Null..

Comment: Nevermind - I had null values still sitting in the [End Date]. Thanks so much for this!